# Extrapolation of definition of derivative from an interval to more general subsets of the real line

Tags: real-analysis

The following is Rudin's definition in PoMA:

Let $f$ be defined in $[a,b]$. For any $x\in [a,b]$ form the quotient

$$ \phi(t) = \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} , ~ t\in (a,b)\setminus\{x\}$$

and define $f'(x) = \lim_{t \to x} \phi(t)$. $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if this limit exists.

What is the proper definition for more general subsets, e.g., the whole real line? It can't be it exists such $[a,b]$ since then $|x|$ has a derivative at $0$ if regarded as a function in $\mathbb{R}$. Would enforcing $x$ interior to $[a,b]$ be better?

---

redacted. See answer

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you want here.  Rudin is defining a derivative relative to the set of points at which the function is defined.  Hence, for example, if $f$ is defined only on $[a,b]$ then $f'(a)$ is really just what some of us would call a right-handed derivative. Generally if $f:E\to \mathbb R$ and $x\in E $ is a not an isolated point of $E$ then there is no difficulty in defining $$f'(x)=\lim_{t \to x,\, t\in E} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}.$$   I would prefer myself to write this as $f_E'(x)$ to remind myself that this derivative is computed *relative* to the set $E$ where $f$ is defined.

Comment: And your final question: "Would enforcing $x$ to be interior" to the domain of $f$ be better?  Most calculus books do indeed define derivatives only at interior points.   So in a calculus class if you are studying a function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$  the derivative $f'(x)$ is defined only for $-1<x<1$ and the "derivatives" if any at the end points written as $f_+'(-1)$ and $f_-'(1)$.

Comment: I've edited the OP, it should be easier to understand my problem with Rudin's use of it now.For instance, he talks about the derivative of $f/g$ at any $x$ where both are differentiable and $g(x)\neq 0$. From what I understand we would need to limit $f/g$ to a neighb. (possibly sided) where it is well defined, the OP now tries to prove that the specific neighb. choosen is irrelevant.

Comment: I would be a lot more comfortable if he had used your initial definition on $E$ tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was a bit too focused in the $\phi$ usage/domain. The $\epsilon-\delta$ interpretation of the limit is a bit more useful here.

If Rudin says $f$ is differentiable at $x$, an interior point of its domain, we can only assume he means that $f_{|[a,b]}$ is for some $[a,b]$ with $x\in(a,b)$ - otherwise it is an ambiguous statement since $|x|$ would have two possible values at $0$. Note that any $[a,b]$ will do, the existence of the limit of the quotient is equivalent for all of them and the value - if it exists- is also equal.

If $x$ is not a limit point of the domain then the only explanation is he meant $f:[x,b]\to R$ or $f:[a,x]\to R$. Again the specific length of these intervals is immaterial for existence/value of the derivative.

This interpretation solves the problem with $(f/g)'=f'g+fg'$: since $g$ is continuous at $x\in [a,b]$ we can find a neighb.(possibly sided) of it in which $g(t)\neq 0$ and $f/g$ is well defined. If $x$ is a extremity of the interval we used the 2nd paragraph, if it is interior then we use the first.